# how to add color to each data in chartjs scatter plot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

```
let dataSet = [];
  Object.keys(stateData).map((item) => {
    let short = {};
    let medium = {};
    let long = {};
    if (stateData[item].horizon === "Short-term") {
      short["label"] = "Short-term";
      short["pointBackgroundColor"]="rgba(201, 120, 12, 1)"
      short["x"] = stateData[item].impact;
      short["y"] = stateData[item].occurrence;
      dataSet.push(short);
    }
    if (stateData[item].horizon === "Medium-term") {
      medium["label"] = "Medium-Term";
      medium["pointBackgroundColor"]="rgba(201, 120, 12, 1)"
      medium["x"] = stateData[item].impact;
      medium["y"] = stateData[item].occurrence;
      dataSet.push(medium);
    }
    if (stateData[item].horizon === "Long-term") {
      long["label"] = "Long-Term";
      long["pointBackgroundColor"]="rgba(201, 120, 12, 1)"
      long["x"] = stateData[item].impact;
      long["y"] = stateData[item].occurrence;
      dataSet.push(long);
    }
  });


  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: dataSet,
      }
    ]
  };
  const options = {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Risks"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 0.5
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 0.5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-9/12">
      <div className="chartjs-wrapper">
        <Scatter data={data} options={options} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the above code is what i was trying to do is plotting the scatter plot using chartjs and conditionally rendering the pointbackground color based on the data wheather the data belong to short term or long term or medium term but i was unable to give the different colors to these different terms can any one please help me with this

Comment: Can you post a link to CodeSandbox? It would be easy to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under your `let dataSet` put another array `let backgroundColor` and instead of setting pointBackgroundColor in your objects in the if, push that collor into the array, after that add this array to the dataset as backgroundColors so you will get something like this:

```
  let dataSet = [];
  let backgroundColor: [];  

  Object.keys(stateData).map((item) => {
    let short = {};
    let medium = {};
    let long = {};
    if (stateData[item].horizon === "Short-term") {
      short["label"] = "Short-term";
      backgroundColor.push("rgba(201, 120, 12, 1)")
      short["x"] = stateData[item].impact;
      short["y"] = stateData[item].occurrence;
      dataSet.push(short);
    }
    if (stateData[item].horizon === "Medium-term") {
      medium["label"] = "Medium-Term";
      backgroundColor.push("rgba(201, 120, 12, 1)")
      medium["x"] = stateData[item].impact;
      medium["y"] = stateData[item].occurrence;
      dataSet.push(medium);
    }
    if (stateData[item].horizon === "Long-term") {
      long["label"] = "Long-Term";
       .push("rgba(201, 120, 12, 1)")
      long["x"] = stateData[item].impact;
      long["y"] = stateData[item].occurrence;
      dataSet.push(long);
    }
  });


  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: dataSet,
        backgroundColor
      }
    ]
  };
  const options = {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Risks"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 0.5
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 0.5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-9/12">
      <div className="chartjs-wrapper">
        <Scatter data={data} options={options} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```